# c++ assigning value to struct member through shared pointer causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, struct, smart-pointers

Good day.  I'm refreshing my C++ knowledge after not using it since the late 90s and am getting up-to-speed on new things.  Today, my question is on shared pointers and structs.

Here's my code:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int x;
};

int main() {
  shared_ptr<struct A> y;
  y->x =0;

  return 0;
}
```

compile string:

```
g++ -Wall -Wpedantic --std=gnu++11 -g test.cpp -o test
```

valgrind memcheck notes there's an "Invalid write of size 4" on line 11, which is y->x = 0

So, my question is: why is there an invalid write?  My understanding--obviously faulty--is that the shared_ptr idiom will handle allocation and de-allocation of memory for the thing it's pointed to, and indeed this happens when I use it to point to primitive types and classes as far as I can tell, but this case of using it with a struct is tripping me up.

The real use case I'm trying to figure out is using a smart pointer to store a struct sockaddr_in, but I figure I should (re)learn to crawl before I learn to build smart pointers to objects defined in a time before smart pointers were a widely-accepted thing.

Thanks.

Comment: structs are the same as classes - the only different is the default member protection - so `shared_ptr` works exactly the same for structs as it does for classes. It does not handle allocation at all though, only deallocation.

Comment: `shared_ptr<struct A>` - the `struct` there is completely redundant. In C, you needed `struct` since the compilers back then were too stupid to look up `A`, but this has never been needed in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
shared_ptr<struct A> y;
```

That's an *empty* pointer, which doesn't point to (or own) any object. You can't dereference it.

You'll need to create an object to be managed by the pointer, for example:

```
auto y = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<A> y {new A};
```

The first is usually preferred, since it can allocate memory more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to allocate your object with `new` or with [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Comment: Geez.... thanks.  I can't believe I forgot that.  Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Accept the answer of Mike Seymour.  It's more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
std::shared_ptr<struct A> p = std::make_shared<struct A>();
```

Share_Ptr is a wrapper for raw pointers, it doesn't allocate memory  for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of struct A. Then you point with pointer y to it.